# What does this symbol mean in Game Of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game Of Thrones, we see this symbol associated with the white walkers twice (that I remember, might be more).

I don't remember any explanation about it in the show.
 Is there any explanation in the books about the meaning of it (or maybe I missed it in the show)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Obviously, unofficial but /r/Freefolk [has their own interpretation](https://www.reddit.com/r/freefolk/comments/bok00m/it_all_makes_sense_now_it_was_being_foreshadowed/) of its meaning as a metaforeshadowing [Season 8 Spoilers].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the symbol present when the Night King was made by the Children of the Forest.

[image]

Unfortunately the Night King and all his followers died before they could explain the significance or meaning of the symbol. Perhaps it was a battle standard? A herald of the Night King's defiance against his creators?

We would never know now.

P.S The Night King does not exist in the books except as a legendary figure similar to Lann the Clever and Ser Serwyn of the Mirror Shield.

Comment: Correct, though technically the Night King and Night's King are actually different characters sharing a similar name. Night's King, as far as we know, wasn't a White Walker but instead a Lord Commander who had relations with a female WW.